# Paging in ASP web page?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010

I'm new to this so forgive me if this is trivial. Anyway, I'm creating a simple ASP web page that reports data from a table in a database that has 5 items in it. I use a GridView to display the data and that works fine, but I'd like to limit the results to three items so that I can allow paging. I tried configuring the select statement from something like "select * from country" to

```
select * from country limit 3
```

but I get a "There was an error executing the query" message when I try to test it. Is there some other way that I have to do this?

Comment: What kind of database are you using? In MS SQL the query would be `select top 3 * from country`.

Comment: no its set up on my computer from SQL Server, im only running the app on a localhost

Comment: alex- ok just tested that and it works. Thanks! This is my first time using MS SQL so i wasn't too familiar with syntax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set Gridview's property `PageSize=3`

Comment: This is not always a good idea as it will pull all the table from db, and do the filtering on client. It is more efficient to limit the data before pulling.

Comment: @Alex: OP has mentioned that it has only 5 records, so it is not a issue.

Comment: @Thomas - I'm not saying that it is an issue, I'm just saying that it is less efficient.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use TOP keyword instead if you use SQL Server database:

```
SELECT TOP 3 * FROM COUNTRY;
```

Answer (score 1):

To do this in SQL Server you need to use `top`

```
select top 3 * from country
```

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the total number of records you are expecting to have in the country table a simple solution would be to use the [`asp:DataPager`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.datapager.aspx) control without any limits on the number of rows returned from the SQL.

This will handle all the paging for you, however the full data set is retained in the page view state and so is not an appropriate solution is you are expecting 1000's of records.